# Why is OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display :?

Tags: opengl, cygwin, xterm, glx

I am trying to use cygwin to analyze large amounts of data. I've installed all the gl, openGL, freeglut packages, but I keep getting this error message when I run the program that graphs the data input:  freeglut (./graph): OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0.0'

Everything else about the program works properly, just the extension seems to not work.

Comment: It seems likely that you're missing a driver for your graphics card. By Cygwin do you mean that you're trying to run this on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

GLX is the transport protocol for OpenGL over X11, i.e. using OpenGL in combination with a X11 server. Windows doesn't speak the X11 protocol natively, so Cygwin ships with a X11 server that sits on top of the Windows GDI; but the Cygwin X11 server *does not* support OpenGL.

Technically it's totally feasible to implement this, i.e. provide a libGL.so that sits on top of `%SYSDIR%/opengl32.dll` for *Direct Rendering* and having the Cygwin-Server create OpenGL contexts and all. But nobody did it so far.

So what you must do (unfortunately) is to use the native Windows OpenGL context creation methods.

Comment: There are lots of X servers that do support GLX on Windows, some free, some for $, but I'd certainly recommend that route before porting code to Windows.

Comment: @NathanKidd: That's why I explicitly wrote about the Cygwin X server. AFAIK Xming has OpenGL support. But there's a catch. Those will usually all be indirect rendering. That by itself was not such a big deal, given modern GPU's cater to that. The problem is, that the indirect rendering protocol was not maintained to keep up with the rest of OpenGL. Which essentially means that you're pretty much stuck with OpenGL-1.x + a handful of extensions… for which you need support in the GLX client library.

Comment: @NathanKidd: Technically a "GLX-3" is totally feasible (actually easier done than a "GLX-2") but someone has to actually do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is tangental to your question, but if for whatever reason Cygwin X isn't supporting GLX you should consider using [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) which does.